# How to create nested paragraphs items programmatically?

Tags: 7, paragraphs

Basically, i am programmatically generating a node. Those nodes have several anidated paragraphs like this:

```
-title parent
 -body parent
 -links parent
 -title child
   -body child
   -links child

-another parent
 ..etc..
```

I'm doing this with paragraphs, i have a parent paragraph that includes another.
At the time of generating the node i'm generating in a sufficient manner the parent paragraph with the following code:
('*field_contenido_padre*' is the field that contains the parent paragraph)

```
$paragraph = new ParagraphsItemEntity(
      array(
        'field_name' => 'field_contenido_padre',
        'bundle' => 'acordeon'));
$paragraph->is_new = TRUE;
$paragraph->setHostEntity('node', $parent);
$paragraph->field_titulo_acordeon[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = $value["title"];
$paragraph->field_body[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = "jajaja";

$ia = 0;
foreach ($value["items"] as $k => $item){
    $paragraph->field_link_archivo[LANGUAGE_NONE][$ia]['title'] = $item;
    $paragraph->field_link_archivo[LANGUAGE_NONE][$ia]['url'] = $value["items"][((int) $k + 1)];
}
$paragraph->save();
```

OK. this works.
Following further from here is my problem.
Now i would like to attach a child paragraph to this recently generated parent paragraph.
I've tried the following with no success:

1. first, generate the child paragraph
   ('*field_acordeon_hijo*' is the field in parent paragraph that contains the child)

> ```
> $paragraph = new ParagraphsItemEntity(
>     array(
>       'field_name' => 'field_acordeon_hijo',
>       'bundle' => 'acordeon-hijo'));
> $paragraph->is_new = TRUE;
> $paragraph->setHostEntity('paragraphs_item', $parent);
> $paragraph->field_titulo_acordeon_hijo[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] ='TITULAko Hijo';
> $paragraph->body[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = 'jajaja';
> $paragraph->save();
> ```

2. Now i try to save the recent child into the parent's container field:

   ```
    $entity = entity_load('paragraphs_item', array($parent->item_id));  
    $entity = reset($entity);  
    $entity->field_acordeon_hijo[LANGUAGE_NONE] = array(
        0 => array(
          'value' => $id_child,
          'safe_value' => $id_child,
          'format ' => NULL));   
    $entity->revision = TRUE;   
    $entity->save(FALSE);
   ```

I get no errors, the parent paragraph is generated fine, but i don't see the children paragraphs :-/

I guess it's because I'm attaching the child to the parent, while maybe I must attach it to the node; but in that case, how to point the child to the parent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After two days, finally, i got it working.
Step 3 is not necessary. My error was in step 2, where I wrote badly the bundle name :-(
so it was

```
new ParagraphsItemEntity(
    array(
      'field_name' => 'field_acordeon_hijo',
      'bundle' => 'acordeon_hijo'))
```

note the underscore in **acordeon_hijo**