# Create nested paragraphs programmatically

Tags: paragraphs

Similar to the question [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/245679/how-to-create-nested-paragraphs-items-programmatically) but for D8. I've managed to create the child paragraphs but failing to generate the parent paragraphs and attaching the child to them.

```
$questions = [];

foreach($data['questions'] as $question) {
    $answers = [];
    foreach($question['answers'] as $answer) {
        $correct = $answer['field_correct'] === 'Yes' ? 1 : 0;

        $answers[] = Paragraph::create([
            'type' => 'quiz_answers',
            'field_answer' => $answer['field_answer'],
            'field_correct' => $correct,
        ])->save();
    }

    $questions[] = Paragraph::create([
        'type' => 'quiz_question',
        'field_question' => $question['field_question'],
        'field_answers' => $answers,
    ])->save();
}


$new_submission = Node::create([
    'type' => 'quiz_submissions',
    'title' => 'Quiz Submission',
    'field_quiz' => $data['quizID'],
    'field_question_submission' => $questions,
]);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Programmatically append multiple paragraphs to entity reference field on node](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/236544/programmatically-append-multiple-paragraphs-to-entity-reference-field-on-node)

Comment: @Hudri thanks, that does help. But my issue is with the child paragraphs. I have an unlimited question paragraph and within it an unlimited answers paragraph. I can create either one but failing to do rest because of the 'unlimited' param.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`save()` returns the status of the save operation, not the entity. And you probably don't need to save the paragraphs, saving the node should save new paragraphs automatically.

So you can try this version:

```
$questions = [];

foreach($data['questions'] as $question) {
    $answers = [];
    foreach($question['answers'] as $answer) {
        $correct = $answer['field_correct'] === 'Yes' ? 1 : 0;

        $answers[] = Paragraph::create([
            'type' => 'quiz_answers',
            'field_answer' => $answer['field_answer'],
            'field_correct' => $correct,
        ]);
    }

    $questions[] = Paragraph::create([
        'type' => 'quiz_question',
        'field_question' => $question['field_question'],
        'field_answers' => $answers,
    ]);
}


$new_submission = Node::create([
    'type' => 'quiz_submissions',
    'title' => 'Quiz Submission',
    'field_quiz' => $data['quizID'],
    'field_question_submission' => $questions,
]);
$new_submission->save();
```

Comment: Indeed, didn't need to save them. Works perfectly fine now.

Comment: Very cool, that we can save paragraphs along with nodes, and no need to set $paragraph->id() as referenced value. Thanks

Comment: I wonder, can we pass raw arrays instead of creating the paragraph objects? If we do, will the paragraph objects be created automatically?