# How to programmatically append a Paragraph to another Paragraph?

Tags: 9, paragraphs

I have a node (e.g. a business "company") with a paragraph referenced field (suppose business "sector", with multiple fields). This paragraph has in its fields a reference to another paragraph (suppose "employee" with multiple fields, one of this is a reference to a taxonomy term).
In a `hook_form_submit()`, with `$form` and `FormStateInterface $form_state` as parameters, I need to programmatically associate multiple employees paragraph to a sector paragraph.

```
...
$node = Node::load($id);
$sector = Paragraph::load($node->get('field_sector')->target_id);

/**
 * List of taxonomy terms loaded elsewhere.
 * I've added a custom elment to the select with "_all" employees
 * in order to associate programmatically all the employees to the $sector.
 * 
 * @var array $employees
 */
foreach ($employees as $employee) {
    $paragraph = Paragraph::create([
        'type' => 'employee',
    ]);
    $paragraph->set('field_name', $employee->get('field_name')->value);
    $paragraph->set('field_age', $employee->get('field_age')->value);
    ...
    $paragraph->save();

    $sector->set('field_employee', $paragraph); // here I don't know how to append to the sector
    $sector->save();
}
```

I tried to associate each $employee to the $sector but with `$sector->set('field_employee', $paragraph);` syntax or with `$sector->appendItem($paragraph)`, that works for nodes, it doesn't work.

Is there a way to programmatically add one paragraph to another?

Visualizing the question, in the image below, when I save the entity with custom option "All employees" (`_all`) selected, I'd like to attach all the 4 paragraph employees associated to the "a selected sector" paragraph (removing `_all`).

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT 1**

I saw the suggested answer [Programmatically append multiple paragraphs to entity reference field on node](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/236544/106556) but it resolve how to attach a Paragraph to a `$node`, not a Paragraph to a Paragraph of the `$node`.

I've try also this:

```
$employee->setParentEntity($sector, 'field_of_reference');
$employee->save();
```

but still does not append the `$employee` to the `$sector`.

**EDIT 2**

I've try to follow the suggested posts but I can't figure how to adapt that code inside a `hook_form_submit()`.

Thanks anyway to all, I think its a bad construction on my code.

[image: This is the entity form with paragraphs inside]

Comment: Have you tried $sector->field_employee[] = $paragraph?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Programmatically append multiple paragraphs to entity reference field on node](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/236544/programmatically-append-multiple-paragraphs-to-entity-reference-field-on-node)

Comment: Have you tried NOT saving the child entity, only the parent entity?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create nested paragraphs programmatically](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/292832/create-nested-paragraphs-programmatically)

Comment: I'll try to follow this post. Maybe you are right, it's a problem related to the entity on which to append the paragraph. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

The problems start with how you load the paragraph. You can't load it like a stand-alone entity:

```
$sector = Paragraph::load($node->get('field_sector')->target_id);
```

Instead load it via the reference field:

```
$sector = $node->get('field_sector')->entity;
```

Then you can add newly created paragraphs without saving, also nested ones, and when you are ready you can save the parent entity.

See [Create nested paragraphs programmatically](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/292832/create-nested-paragraphs-programmatically)

Comment: @robdex Did this work for you?